# WebDataGrid with more than 50 pages does not show the page links after 50

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

The WebDataGrid in my application is only showing a maximum of 50 pages only. Each page size I have set is 25 as per the client requirement. How can I make it to show pages numbered 51, 52, 53,...... also? Please let me know if there is any property that I can set for this or some other way to get around this. Thanks for the help....

Comment: Can't help cause I don't work with WebDataGrid, however [this post](http://blogs.infragistics.com/aspnet/articles/learn-to-build-a-webdatagrid-custom-pager.aspx) on Infragistics site could help you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1. Change your PagerMode to one of the options that has next and previous.  You can see the [PagerMode Enumeration](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Web.v11.2~Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.PagerMode.html) for all the options.
2. Use a custom paging template which will give you more control.  There is an example in the [Online Documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WebDataGrid_Using_Custom_Paging_Template.html).